# nested for each loop to store data in json object

Tags: java, json

I am trying to store the data into json object in the below format:

```
{"mobile:":[{"price":"Rs. abc","name":"def"},{"price":"Rs. ghi","name":"jkl"},....}]}
```

I am trying in the below way but iam not getting desired output code is below:

```
Elements mobilename = document.select(
"#products div.product-unit div.pu-title ");
Elements price = document.select(
"#products div.product-unit div.pu-price div.pu-final span.fk-font-17");

for(Element url1:mobilename)
{
text=url1.text();
System.out.println(text);
for(Element b:price)
{
    text1= b.text();

    System.out.println(text1);

    arr1.add(text1);
    arr1.add(text);
}

pa.put("price",text1 );
pa.put("name", text);
obj7.add(pa);
}
json.put("mobile:", obj7);
```

I am getting the same mobile name and  price in all the arrays.

Thank You.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete. I am missing the declaration of any variable.

Comment: Thank You for your reply, Joeblade, I am scraping the mobile name and price from the web page and i am storing the data in the json object.I updated the code

Comment: I used jsoup.jar and json.simple.1.1.1.jar

Comment: object declaration is : JSONObject pa=new JSONObject(); JSONArray arr1=new JSONArray(); JSONArray obj7 = new JSONArray(); JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

Answer (score 0):

I would use Jackson mapper for this. You can find it [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome)

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public static class YourObject {
    private List<Mobile> mobile;
    // add getter + setter for mobile
}

public static class Mobile {
    private String price;
    private String name;
    // add getter+setter for price and name
}

YourObject obj = new YourObject();
obj.setMobile(new Mobile[] { new Mobile("price1", "name1"), new Mobile("price2", "name2") });

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
```